Do Loop not iterating properly in SAS
I am attempting to finalize the code below, but unfortunately the r1 value is maxing out at 16 while the r value is maxing out at 18.
There seems to be some issue with the way I am looping through n1, n, r1 and r, but I am unable to identify the issue.
Code:
    %MACRO s(
    p0=,    
    p1=,    
    alpha=,
    beta=,  
    usern= 
);

data s_designs;
    keep P0_s P1_s n_s n1_s n2_s r1_s r_s ESS_s PET_s;

    do n = 2 to &usern;
        do n1 = 1 to (n - 1);
            n2 = n - n1;
            do r1 = 0 to n1;
                PET_P0 = cdf('BINOMIAL', r1, &p0, n1);
                PET_P1 = cdf('BINOMIAL', r1, &p1, n1);
                 do r = (r1+1) to &usern;
                    P0_s = 1 - cdf('BINOMIAL', r, &p0, n);
                    P1_s = 1 - cdf('BINOMIAL', r, &p1, n);
                    do l = (r1 + 1) to min(n1, r);
                        if r - l > 0 and n - r > 0 then do;
                            add_P0 = pdf('BINOMIAL', l, &p0, n1) * cdf('BINOMIAL', r - l, &p0, n2);
                            add_P1 = pdf('BINOMIAL', l, &p1, n1) * cdf('BINOMIAL', r - l, &p1, n2);
                            if P0_s <= &alpha and P1_s >= 1 - &beta then do;
                                n_s = n;
                                n1_s = n1;
                                n2_s = n2;
                                r1_s = r1;
                                r_s = r;
                                PET_s = PET_P0;
                                ESS_s = n * PET_P0 + n1 * (1 - PET_P0);
                                output;
                            end;
                        end;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
run;

%MEND s;

%s(
    p0 = 0.3,
    p1 = 0.5,
    alpha = 0.1,
    beta = 0.1,
    usern = 46
);

The code is generally operating correctly except the looping iterators are not ranging from the minimum to maximum values.
In this example, r1 should span from 0 to n1, r from r1+1 to n, and n1 from 1 to n-1.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Which order of operations did you intend SAS to use when evaluating this condition? if r - l > 0 and n - r > 0 then  Are you trying to test if l > 0 or whether 0 and N is true? Or something else? Try adding () into the expression to make sure it does the test you wanted.

@Tom I have added parentheses to that particular line of code. It checks to see whether or not ((n-r)>0) and ((r-l)>0). Unfortunately updating this line as well as adding if min(n1,r) < (r1+1) then byvalue = -1;
else byvalue = 1;
do l = (r1 + 1) to min(n1, r) by byvalue;
does not resolve the issue.

Can you be specific about what is missing?  Note that when I run your macro with USERN=18 I get zero observations written.  Is that what you expect?

I suspect that the issue is with the l do loop.
do l = (r1 + 1) to min(n1, r);

There are conditions when (r1 + 1) is greater than min(n1, r) so that loop will not execute unless you have by -1 in the statement. The output statement is inside this do loop so these records never get written to the output data set.
If you want this loop to iterate backwards, you could calculate the byvalue variable to be equal to 1 or -1 as required, then use it in the do loop:
if min(n1,r) < (r1+1) then byvalue = -1;
else byvalue = 1;
do l = (r1 + 1) to min(n1, r) by byvalue;

